# What's this (flamenco?) rhythm called? (Tres Lagrimas)

Tags: rhythm, flamenco

This song by Guitarra Azul has a very distinctive rhythm that I have also heard in other songs. How is it called? Is it one of the classical flamenco rhythms?

Comment: This is a tango. There are a couple variations of the rhythm but the one heard here is the most common, wih the upright bass playing a bassline with the rhythmic pattern (**1!** + 2 **+! 3!** + **4!**)

Comment: At 3:18, you can also see that guy playing a 3:2 son clave rhythm on the wood clave

Comment: @Aric thanks. According to this [link](https://flamencobites.com/main/flamenco-rhythm-tangos.html), typical tango is 8 beats, accented as 1 **2 3 4** 5 **6 7 8**. But this song seems more like 1 2 **3** 4 5 6 **7** 8.

Comment: according to [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/5263/32406) and what I was taught in highschool, the tango is characterised by having four beats in a bar and having an emphasis on the "and" of beat two. I would also like to add that the video of the man playing on the link you gave also uses this rhythm

Comment: If you were to count at double speed and put 8 notes in a bar, the rhythm would be (**1** 2 3 **4 5** 6 **7** 8)

Comment: @Aric: You could combine your comments into a nice answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Thanks to guidot for reminding me about this question.*

---

**This is a tango.** There are a couple different tango rhythms. The most common one (and the one used in this video, played clearly on the upright bass) is tango rhythm 1 in the diagram below:

[image]

As seen in the diagram and according to [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/5263/32406), tango rhythms are characterised by having four beats in a bar and having an emphasis on the "and" of beat two. Both of the rhythms above fit these criteria.

Another point of interest is the 3:2 son clave rhythm being played on the wood claves at [3:18 in the video](https://youtu.be/-XTAK0avUEw?t=198). The 3:2 and 2:3 rhythms are as follows (2:3 is just 3:2 but the other way round)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

agreed this is a Typical Bolero with a 3:2 then 2:3 Clave Pattern - I wrote this song in 2005 for my Group Guitarra Azul on our first Album! I hope you Like it!

Comment: Welcome, Stefano!

Comment: Thanks for your comment Steve! I really enjoy the music of Guitarra Azul.